# connect to sqlplus without writing as sysdba

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I want to connect `sqlplus sys/test` without writing `as sysdba`.
I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid that.

Comment: All I really need to ask, is **why**? The `SYS` account should only be used to perform DBA activities, so you wouldn't even want to login as it without "`as sysdba`". You can do `sqlplus / as sysdba` if you want to type less.

Comment: because I have a script shell i use to connect to sqlplus, I need just to type sqlplus sys/test without "as sys dba", I did it before but I forgot where I found how to do it :(

Comment: @Phil you can only use `sqlplus / as sysdba` if you have run the `orapwd` utility. @amine you cannot. Think it is meant as some safety to prevent easy use of the `sys` user which should only be used in special cases. Use a different user (with just enough rights) to do you (DBA) work.

Comment: @Marco `sqlplus / as sysdba` doesn't require running `orapwd`. It uses OS authentication, based on group membership. It has nothing to do with a password file.

Comment: "because I have a script shell i use to connect to sqlplus" doesn't really answer the question of why you want to connect as SYS without SYSDBA privileges.  What is this script doing?  Why does it even need to connect as SYS at all? Why not as some other user with just enough privs to do the task at hand?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ alias sqs='sqlplus / as sysdba'
$ sqs

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Wed Jun 15 20:33:31 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP, Advanced Analytics
and Real Application Testing options

SQL>
```